# how can I call tab key event in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

Here is my simple data

> John Smith            Individual            010987654

I have three textboxes and the above data will automatically insert in the first textbox of my web page.

My problem is

How can I make as soon as data is inserted in the textbox *(means when textbox’s onchange event is fired)*

1. First, javascript will find ‘tab’ space in this string
2. Second, if find ‘tab’ space in the string, javascript will press ‘tab’ key and insert data in the another text box.

Comment: Try *reading* the helpful tag pop-ups before applying them to a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plain old DOM-0 JavaScript solution, just for fun.

```
document.getElementById('the_form').onchange = function() {
    var field = this[0];
    var parts = field.value.split('\t');
    for (var i = 0; field = this[i]; i++) {
        field.value = parts[i] || '';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vKaxP/

Answer (score 1):

I thought you want to split those texts into different textboxes, so I got something like:

```
$("#a").change(function(){
    var s = $(this).val();
    if (s.match(/\t+/)) {
        var a = s.split(/\t+/);
        $('#a').val(a[0]);
        $('#b').val(a[1]);
        $('#c').val(a[2]);
    }
});
```

if you type `a b c` into the first input box, press `tab` or `enter`, `b` and `c` would appear into other textboxes, repectively.

I use `\s`(space) for test in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gongzhitaao/La5dm/).  You could just change it to `\t` for tab.

Comment: @JavaLearner u r welcome. But this code not good and buggy. I like Dagg Nabbit's :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is prototype of what you need to do.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input id="a" />
</div>
<div>
    <input id="b" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#a').on('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    // Test if string has a tab:
    if (/\t/.test(value)) {
        // Just set the value of the other text box
        // And set focus:
        // Using jQuery that would be:
        $('#b').val(value).focus();
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/XmArP/

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the question as "The server puts all the data into one field, tab separated, and I want to split it up into several textfields", then try this:

On load:

```
var fields = [$("#firstField"), $("#secondField"), $("#thirdField")];
var data = fields[0].val().split(/\t/);

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fields[i].val(data[i]);
}
```